# Load a file and save it in a variable in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

Let's say I have a pdf file in local file system at `/public/rendered/sample.pdf`.

I am trying to upload this file to AWS S3 now (basically from local to remote). I have a customized function to upload the file to AWS S3 and I confirmed it is working. Let's say that function is `upload_to_s3`.

I need to somehow access the `sample.pdf` and save it into a variable called `file` and pass this variable as a parameter in `upload_to_s3(file)`.

However, I cannot figure out how to access the file.

I tried following `file = File.read("public/rendered/sample.pdf")` but it gives me an error saying `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` when I run `upload_to_s3(file)`.

Would love to get any advice!

Comment: Access the file directly using the S3 URL?

Comment: @error2007s, no accessing the file in local filesystem. I'm trying to access the local file and pass that into a method which will upload the file to S3.

Comment: @JoHksi if the file is accessible at http://yourdomain.com/public/rendered/sample.pdf then the advice above stands -- bust pass the url to S3 and it will fetch it for you.